# Is the output week number string correct?

Tags: python, time, week-number

I'm trying to generate week number string using Python **time** module, considering week starts on **Sunday**.

If my interpretation of the official [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html) is correct then this can be achieved by the following code:

```
import time 

time.strftime("%U", time.localtime())
>> 37
```

My question is, is the above output correct? Shouldn't the output be 38 instead, considering the below details:

My timezone is IST (GMT+5:30)

```
import time

#Year
time.localtime()[0]
>> 2019

#Month
time.localtime()[1]
>> 9

#Day
time.localtime()[2]
>> 18
```

Comment: Are you expecting the ISO week number? That's calculated slightly differently: [*"The ISO 8601 year and ISO 8601 week directives are not interchangeable with the year and week number directives above."*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=datetime#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the output is correct. Week 1 started on January 6th, as that was the first Sunday in 2019. January 1st through 5th were week 0:

```
>>> time.strftime('%U', time.strptime("2019-1-1", "%Y-%m-%d"))
'00'
>>> time.strftime('%U', time.strptime("2019-1-6", "%Y-%m-%d"))
'01'
```

This is covered in the documentation:

> All days in a new year preceding the first Sunday are considered to be in week 0.

You are perhaps looking for the [*ISO week date*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date), but note that in this system the first day of the week is a Monday.

You can get the week number using that system with the [`datetime.date.isocalendar()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.isocalendar), or by formatting with `%V`:

```
>>> time.strftime("%V", time.localtime())
'38'
>>> from datetime import date
>>> date.today().isocalendar()  # returns ISO year, week, and weekday
(2019, 38, 2)
>>> date.today().strftime("%V")
'38'
```

Comment: @jonrsharpe: `isocalendar()` uses a *different definition of a week number*

Comment: Yes, but presumably that's what's confused the OP.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks for the detailed explanation. I overlooked the part where it says  "All days in a new year preceding the first Sunday are considered to be in week 0."

Comment: @MartijnPieters Also, I'm looking for something like ISO Weeknum but something that starts on a Sunday, instead of Monday. 

ISO Week 1 2019 spans from Dec 31st 2018 till 6th Jan. (Mon to Sun). However, by my convention Week 1 2019 should be spanning from Dec 30th 2018 till 5th Jan. (Sun to Mon). How can this be achieved?

Comment: @Newbie92: there are a lot of different week numbering schemes (WikiPedia says there are at least 6[](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Week#Week_numbering)), I'm not so certain that you really want the ISO week numbering scheme adjusted for a Sunday. All I know is that you want weeks to start on Sundays, and that you consider January 1st of this year to be week 1. What week number should the 31st of December 2019 be? In the ISO calendar, that's week 1 of 2020. Or should it be week 53 of 2019? What are the rules for determining the first and last weeks?

Answer (score 0):

It's correct since you start counting from the first Sunday.

> %U - week number of the current year, starting with the first Sunday as the first day of the first week
>   https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/time_strftime.htm

Answer (score 0):

It's correct. Since all days in a new year preceding the first Sunday are considered to be in week 0 (01/01 to 01/05), this week is the week 37.